Gradle Sync Failed: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
I have Android Studio 2024.1.1.12-mac_arm. I built an example Kotlin project. when I open the project I get this Error:
Gradle Sync Failed: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

I try invalid and clean cache. I try to build with file -> sync with gradle file.  I am trying to change my region country. I try to change my internet provider. I am trying to reinstall Android Studio and create a new project. All of them are not to work.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
